# Filter a Data Source from a Different Data Source

Tags: filter, datasource, looker-studio

I have two chart tables both with different data sources. I want one table to act as the filter to the other table.
Here is the problem...

- **I tried a custom query for my data source which used the email parameter to filter the data source.**
- The problem is every time a user changes a filter on any page a query is executed in BigQuery, slowing the results and exponentially increasing my BigQuery monthly charges.
- **I tried blending the two tables.**
- The problem is the blended data feature only allows for 10 dimensions to be added to the resulting blended data source and is very slow.
- **I tried creating a control filter using a custom field on the "location" column on each table sharing the same "Field Id".**
- The problem is that the results table returns all the stores until you click on a location in the control list. And I cannot let a user see other locations.

Here is a link to a data studio sample report you can clearly see what I am trying to do.
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/dd33be45-ab13-4881-8a3b-cabafa8c0dbb

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution which i can recommend to over come your first challenge, i.e. High cost. You can customize cost by using [GCP-Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore), depending on frequency of data that is getting updated.
Moreover, Bigquery also cashes data for a query if you are not using Wild cards on tables and Time partitioned tables. So try to customize your solution over analysis cost if it is feasible over your solution. Bigquery [Partition and Clusting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) may also help you in reducing BQ analysis cost.